# Django Custom widget rendering

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

## The General Problem

Suppose you have a certain model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

And an accompaniying form you use for creation

```
class CreateMyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']
```

In a normal situation, when the form is rendered in a template *I usually loop over the fields in the template*

```
{%for field in form%}
{{field}}
{%endfor%}
```

When custom styling is needed, I usually have to resort to placing my `<div>`s and `<span>`s in that loop, and specify the base widget and its `attrs` in the `Meta` subclass.

Looking through the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/media/) on the topic, I understand that it seems like I have to play with the `Media` subclass to make all the manipulation happen in the `widgets` property in the `Meta`, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

## Specific Problem

Suppose I have a template where `TextInput` forms need to render [as in this template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/):

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="MyModel Name">
</div>
```

How do I go about creating a widget so that I can get the same result by using:

```
class CreateMyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']
        widgets={'name':MyWidget(addon="Name",placeholder="MyModel Name")}
```

I understand that the placeholder is something I can put in the `attrs` initialization of `TextInput`, but the addon (or parent div, in this case) is not *or at least not to my knowledge*

I apologize for a long question, I just felt that I need to thoroughly explain this problem because it's been bothering me for a while...

Comment: in `addon="Name"`, Name is supposed to go inside the span right?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Nope, you can find the rendered form [here](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/forms.html), I'm trying to make something to render fields in the "Input Groups" section

Comment: you will have to create div and span inside the for loop manually, you can use `{{ field.label }}` to put text dynamically inside span

Comment: @VaibhavVishal That's what I have been doing so far, and it gets frustrating having to keep track with lots of HTML in an enterprise application. I'm hoping someone out here has a better solution!

Comment: there are ways to do what you trying to do, but that will require hacking into django and they will just complicate your code even more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can do like below.

## Widget

```
from django import forms
from django.template import loader
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class MyWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'widget_template.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return {'widget': {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
        }}

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

## widget_template.html

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mywidget-{{ widget.name }}" name="{{ widget.name }}" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note that widgets' HTML MUST have a name attribute, or else the Django admin will not be able to read their values, and they will just be silently excluded from the form submission.